# Why doesn't this IBAction work?? iOS Game

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 IBAction's - Start game, and Replay for an IOS game I'm working on. `ViewDidLoad` loads with a lot hidden. Start game makes `ball.hidden = NO;` and other things show, as well as the `NSTimer` to start, and Downmovement etc. When the user dies in the game, the `gameoverscreen.hidden = NO;` and it has a few buttons that come with it. I added a replay button, which I made a new outlet for. I tried taking the start `IBAction` and re-writing the same code in the replay `IBAction`, but it automatically goes back to the gameover screen. I also tried writing out `gameoverscreen.hidden = YES;` again in the replay `IBAction`, but it still does it. Do these conflict some how? Any reasons as to why this is happening. Is there a way to reload a screen.... i.e. is there some sort of code I could write to reload my screen when Replay is clicked on the gameover screen?

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender
{
    start.hidden = YES; //hides button
    stimage.hidden = YES; //hides image
    upMovement = 4;
    movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //when we start game, start timer to run method every 0.05 seconds

    platform1.hidden = NO;
    platform2.hidden = NO;
    ball1.hidden = NO;
    ball2.hidden = NO;

    advertisement.hidden = YES;


    //1
    RandomPosition = arc4random()%248; //48 different possibilities the random number generator can generate
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 36; //generate a value between 36 and 284 try 30
    platform1.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, 530);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please.

Comment: No, @CharanGiri, do you have a solution??

Comment: when you click on Replay button you are calling startGame action right does that method executes. if yes are you hiding the game overview and invalidating the timer and again validating timer

Comment: Yeah, when the gameoverscreen appears the timer is invalidated, and when start is clicked it is validated with "movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];". Start also hides the gameoverscreen again. Thats why I don't understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply run 
    [self viewDidLoad];
This should run the ViewDidLoad function again. If you are using the "startGame" to begin the whole game, run:
    [self startGame:(yourSendingButton)];

Comment: Hmm same problem for some reason :(

Comment: That's odd... Do you set up the whole scene in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yeah :(, it is all set up.

Comment: Is that where everything is put into place?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what happens from the code provided. I thus can only make a wild guess:
I assume that the replay button actually executes its `IBAction`, and that your `gameover` view was indeed hidden, but became "automatically" visible again.
My guess is that your method `moving` is responsible that is called repeatedly by the timer. It might be that this method recognizes that the used died, and makes the gameover visible again.
So, did you reset the living status of the user correctly, and did you stop the timer?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not sure how I would reset the living status of the user because I haven't set anything up like that to begin with. the NSTimer is invalidated when the gameover stuff appears yes :(